# Tooltip is not shown

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm writing a WP 8 app and I want to display a tooltip when mouse hovers over a button or switch. I tried the following code:

```
ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
toolTip.Content = "Flip switch to turn on.";
ToolTipService.SetToolTip(onOffSwitch, toolTip);
```

Also I tried to define it in XAML:

```
<Button Content="Msgs"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="59,651,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="108"
        ToolTipService.ToolTip="tip"/>
```

But none of these work. When I point cursor on the control there is no tip. What did I miss?

Comment: i guess you have followed wrong documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868199.aspx , this is for windows store app.not wp8

Comment: how could you use mouse with a phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First there is no mouse hover in windows phone 8. however if you want to add tooltips, you can refer this [link](http://igrali.com/2012/01/07/show-a-tooltip-for-tapped-pushpin-on-windows-phone/)

Answer (score 2):

You can not add a tooltip for Windows Phone controllers. There is no way to simulate or detect a mouse/finger hover in Windows Phone.